# Why does my Minecraft Nintendo switch instantly crash when getting back into the game?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I turn on my Nintendo Switch, open Minecraft, and I see my Hotbar items have lost their textures and are pink and black checkered, or the blocks around me are pink and black checkered and then my game crashes instantly. My game also randomly stops, so I go to the HOME menu and try to re-enter the game, and it just straight up crashes with the usual "The software was closed because an error occurred" crash handler. Does anybody know why this happens and how I can fix it? It also doesn't matter if I'm playing a pre-built world (Bought in the Minecraft shop) or a vanilla one.

Comment: The pink and black texture is the texture missing texture - interesting that it wasn't able to load most textures EXCEPT that. It also seems to have loaded some of the UI textures but not all. Do you have any addons/texture packs enabled?

Comment: It was happening on my MINECON 2018-19 world, and that has no extra texture packs installed. My "Lucky Blocks!" world has extra textures (Plain, Lucky, Very Lucky, Unlucky, and Very Unlucky Lucky Blocks), but those aren't listed as a texture pack, and it happens to normal blocks as well, so its not the texture packs that are causing the issue.

Comment: It just sounds like that world is corrupted

Comment: Dude, there are multiple worlds where that happens

Comment: @Penguin in your first comment, did you mean to put quotation marks around "texture missing"? I just wanted to know but it's stuck like that now soooooooo yeah

Comment: im not really sure what ur asking? would that make a dofference?

Comment: No, probably not. I'm talking about the comment where you talked about the missing textures

Comment: Thank you to everybody who upvoted my post, you are all really kind and I love the support. Keep being kind!

Comment: who edited this post?

Comment: It is Minecraft Bedrock Edition because this was discontinued 2018, and you say you have a 2018-2019 minecraft world so you dont have the discontinued version

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhh ok then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few easy ways you can attempt that might fix this error:

1. **Check for corrupted data.** Sometimes files can get corrupted on the Nintendo Switch and cause severe issues.  You can fix this by going Data Management in Settings and clicking "Check for Corrupted Data".
2. **Reboot the console.** Although this may seem ridiculously simple, it can sometimes fix the worst errors that can occur.
3. **Make sure all apps are up to date.** Sometimes bugs can occur when older software is running on a new system and vice versa. Check for updates to stop this issue from happening.
4. **Remove the card (or cartridge) and reinstall the game.** Sometimes there are errors that aren't fixed with the above, and uninstalling the game may help with that.
5. **Reset your console.** This is a very extreme decision, but sometimes the entire system may be corrupted. Doing this will sometimes fix the error.

*Source: I found a lot of this information from [here](https://thedroidguy.com/nintendo-switch-software-was-closed-error-1132698) and from my own experience.*

Comment: I have 9 games on a cartridge but Minecraft was on sale on the Nintendo E-shop, so resetting the console would delete the game too. Plus this issue isn't happening with other games (Like Pokemon Shield, which was pre-purchased) so it's probably Minecraft, so I'll check for corrupted data or make sure the game is freshly updated.

Comment: Would resetting the console actually delete all my saves?

Comment: @Kirbychu Yes, but I think they wouldn’t delete if they were stored on the SD card. Not sure though.

Comment: Well, that's good to know because they are all saved to the SD card. I would also assume that pre-downloaded games (downloaded before release)  are automatically saved to the SD card upon finishing the download

Comment: (I said the above comment because I pre-downloaded both Pokemon Shield and Brilliant Diamond on my switch)